# Objects in scala

Tags: scala

```
class Node(var name:String = "") {
  this.name : String = name 
}

x = Node()
y = x

x.name = "Error"

if (x eq y) println(true) else println(false)
```

I have the above code in scala and I don't think I understand how objects work. The above prints out false. The two variables should be equal but they are not. Also if I try y.name is empty. Shouldn't it be th same with x?
What do I use if I want them to modify the same object?

Comment: Objects in scala don't have constructor parameters. Are you sure you're using an `object` and not a `class`?

Comment: sorry i fixed my post. there was a class and from that i created a new object

Comment: How is `name` being set? It seems like a circular reference. can you provide the full code for `Node`?

Comment: your class definition doesn't even compile. perhaps you meant something like `class Node { var name: String = "" }`?

Comment: @wheaties `x` and `y` are pointing to the same address in memory, `x` and `y` should be equal regardless of this not being a `case class` which actually checks field by field based equality.

Comment: Ok still how do I make x = y so that the changes I make to one of the two appear to the other too?

Comment: This code does not compile. Surely, it is not the same version you are using to get the "wrong output". Show us the code you are actually running.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you're defining and using your code, but a simple example in the REPL produces the right results:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Node(var name: String) { }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Node

scala> val node = new Node("hello")
node: Node = Node@3c01cfa1

scala> val otherNode = node
otherNode: Node = Node@3c01cfa1

scala> node.name = "x"
node.name: String = x

scala> node eq otherNode
res0: Boolean = true

scala> otherNode.name
res1: String = x
```

Comment: It doesn't in my program

Comment: @user1663930 Then post a [MCVE] of your problem.